# Add extra field in Rails habtm joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this relationship between users, teams

```
class CreateTeamsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.references :user
        t.references :team
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

The issue is that I want to add extra attribute in HABTM,attribute name is "user_name"
How to do this?

Comment: You want to add `user_name` column to `teams_users`?

Comment: yes I want to add user_name column to teams_users

Comment: Can I ask why when you can clearly reference this through users?

Comment: I only want to add extra field in HABTM(teams_users) table

Comment: The question is why exactly do you want to add this column to `teams_users`?

Comment: Because now the requirement is that every user have different name in each team.That's why I want to add a field user_name in teams_users

Comment: Shouldn't a user name already be unique in the users table? If so just validate in the TeamsUser eg. `validates :user_id, unique:{scope: :team_id}`

Comment: No no user name is not uniqee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of HABTM you'd use `has_many` and `has_many :through`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :team, through: :membership
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base # This would be your old 'join table', now a full model
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version, you can't do what your're trying to do without a little refactoring. Here is how I would do it (apologies if there's syntax issues, I'm doing this from memory I haven't tested the code but the principle is sound)

Create a new model to represent "membership" of a team (maybe call it "Membership") and the associated migration to create the table:

```
class Membership
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then change your team and user models to use this new model:

```
class User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
end

class Team
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Once you've refactored this far, adding additional columns / attributes to "memberships" is easy because you can just treat it like any other model.

Comment: Now how to add additional columns / attributes to "memberships" please help I am confused

Comment: Create a new migration to create_table "memberships" . This would include your new column (other_name). It would allow you to do this:

    user.memberships.each do |m|
      m.other_name
    end

In terms of how to get the actual form working, see the documentation for "accepts_nested_attributes_for"

Comment: @haseeb you just going to disappear? People have taken the time to answer your question here!

Comment: I don't understand what you want say?

Comment: Did you get your issue sorted out? both @Ariejan and I posted what I consider to be the correct answer to your question - you should mark one of them as correct if they helped you or clarify what you were asking if they didn't - don't just vanish!

Comment: Both of solutions help me and I solve my problem.I wanted to mark them before but stackoverflow doesn't allow me because my points are low

Comment: That's okay buddy, glad you got your issue sorted